# What is the name of this kind of connector where you stick a whole board in to connect?

Tags: connector, components, logic-gates

An example of the connector type I'm looking for a name for can be found on this board:

[image]

It's the big box. You stick a board in to it with strips of exposed copper to connect. It also seems similar to how video game carts and USB work.

I'm looking to get my own version of this connector to interface with some old logic packages that I found.

[image]

These boards just have pretty common logic packages on them and they look like one plugs the whole board into something. I would like to design my own board to do this, but I think I need a part like the one on the adafruit board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be called *edge connectors* or *card slot connectors*, just to name two.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a “36 pin double sided 0.1” edge connector “ ( board to wire) commonly used with ribbon cable plugs and interleaved grounds on the bottom side . These breakout boards were for demonstrating old technology IC’s. Circa 1970 TTL

https://ia800807.us.archive.org/25/items/bitsavers_motoroladaTTLIntegratedCircuitsDataBook_38442857/1971_Motorola_TTL_Integrated_Circuits_Data_Book.pdf

But these days it’s faster to use a DIP protoboard or a simulator.